# Android java sound equivalent

Tags: android

Is there an equivalent for Java sound in android? I am trying port a java app to android, where I need to use the java sound sample and data line.

Comment: What does your app do? There are different parts of the api in android that do the same as java sound does, for example if you use it for telephony you can use Android's SIP ect

Comment: [Get Java on Android](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Java-on-Android)

Comment: @Prijm.com : relevance ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may be interested in [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html).  You can stream data to it, as you can with a Java DataLine

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use it https://github.com/google/ringdroid
There is a SoundFile class with all features that you need.

Comment: I don't know about data line, but you can get samples and a lot of other data from this class